# How to predict the time gap between two conditions

Tags: regression, modeling, panel-data

Could anyone suggest the best method to predict the time gap between two events?

For example, given that diabetics are at higher risk of developing hypertension, I would like to predict the time gap until patients develop hypertension after being diagnosed with diabetes.

I will have both time dependent and independent covariates. Does this require a longitudinal approach?

Answer (score 1):

Waiting times are frequently modeled using the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). In order to account for covariates, you could have the parameter of the exponential distribution depend on them. This is usually called "exponential regression". You can do this [in R](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=exponential+regression+in+R&oq=exponential+regression+in+R&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i30j0i8i30l2.1052.7951.0.8718.31.15.2.13.14.0.199.1883.7j8.15.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.-LBXP4ycApk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.Yms&fp=923336b608451a36&biw=1675&bih=1046).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is COX regression appropriate for this situation?

Comment: Cox regression would probably be even better suited to your question that a straightforward exponential regression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_models